# Spring boot issue with deleting child from a parent

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I was hoping to get some advice from you all. I'm enjoying the Spring boot framework but I'm having issues deleting a parent from a grandparent using JPA and Hibernate.

I have a rather complex set up mind you, so i'll quickly explain the layout:

The child (website) can have:

- 1 Product (parent)
- 1 Provider
- Many prices (children)

The parent (product) can have:

- Many websites (children)

The Provider can have:

- Many websites

The Price can have:

- 1 website (parent)

So it's like a Grandparent -> parent -> children relationship. My question is, How can I delete the parent without deleting the Grandparent and Provider?

Here is my class layout:

Grandparent:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "product")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "product", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Website> website;

}
```

Parent:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "website")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Website {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id")
    private @NotNull Product product;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "provider_id")
    private @NotNull Provider provider;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "website", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Price> priceList;
}
```

Provider:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "provider")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Provider {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @JsonIgnore
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "provider", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    private List<Website> website;
}
```

Child:

```
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor(force = true)
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "price")
@Getter
@Setter
public class Price {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "website_id")
    private Website website;
}
```

The controller:

```
@Autowired
private IWebsiteRepository repository;
@RequestMapping(path = "/admin/delete/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView deletePost(@PathVariable("id") long id) {
    repository.delete(id);

    return new ModelAndView("redirect:/price/api/website/admin/");
}
```

The Repository:

```
public interface IWebsiteRepository extends CrudRepository<Website, Long> {
    Website findById(long id);
    List<Website> findAll();
}
```

Delete is the default method here for this repository but it doesn't delete the website. Here is what gets outputted from Hibernate when I hit the delete controller endpoint:

```
Hibernate: select website0_.id as id1_4_, website0_.date as date2_4_, website0_.product_id as product_4_4_, website0_.provider_id as provider5_4_, website0_.url as url3_4_ from website website0_
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_2_0_, product0_.activate as activate2_2_0_, product0_.date as date3_2_0_, product0_.name as name4_2_0_, website1_.product_id as product_4_4_1_, website1_.id as id1_4_1_, website1_.id as id1_4_2_, website1_.date as date2_4_2_, website1_.product_id as product_4_4_2_, website1_.provider_id as provider5_4_2_, website1_.url as url3_4_2_, pricelist2_.website_id as website_4_1_3_, pricelist2_.id as id1_1_3_, pricelist2_.id as id1_1_4_, pricelist2_.date as date2_1_4_, pricelist2_.price as price3_1_4_, pricelist2_.website_id as website_4_1_4_, provider3_.id as id1_3_5_, provider3_.colour as colour2_3_5_, provider3_.date as date3_3_5_, provider3_.name as name4_3_5_, provider3_.target_name as target_n5_3_5_ from product product0_ left outer join website website1_ on product0_.id=website1_.product_id left outer join price pricelist2_ on website1_.id=pricelist2_.website_id left outer join provider provider3_ on website1_.provider_id=provider3_.id where product0_.id=?
Hibernate: select product0_.id as id1_2_0_, product0_.activate as activate2_2_0_, product0_.date as date3_2_0_, product0_.name as name4_2_0_, website1_.product_id as product_4_4_1_, website1_.id as id1_4_1_, website1_.id as id1_4_2_, website1_.date as date2_4_2_, website1_.product_id as product_4_4_2_, website1_.provider_id as provider5_4_2_, website1_.url as url3_4_2_, pricelist2_.website_id as website_4_1_3_, pricelist2_.id as id1_1_3_, pricelist2_.id as id1_1_4_, pricelist2_.date as date2_1_4_, pricelist2_.price as price3_1_4_, pricelist2_.website_id as website_4_1_4_, provider3_.id as id1_3_5_, provider3_.colour as colour2_3_5_, provider3_.date as date3_3_5_, provider3_.name as name4_3_5_, provider3_.target_name as target_n5_3_5_ from product product0_ left outer join website website1_ on product0_.id=website1_.product_id left outer join price pricelist2_ on website1_.id=pricelist2_.website_id left outer join provider provider3_ on website1_.provider_id=provider3_.id where product0_.id=?
Hibernate: select website0_.provider_id as provider5_4_0_, website0_.id as id1_4_0_, website0_.id as id1_4_1_, website0_.date as date2_4_1_, website0_.product_id as product_4_4_1_, website0_.provider_id as provider5_4_1_, website0_.url as url3_4_1_, product1_.id as id1_2_2_, product1_.activate as activate2_2_2_, product1_.date as date3_2_2_, product1_.name as name4_2_2_ from website website0_ inner join product product1_ on website0_.product_id=product1_.id where website0_.provider_id=?
```

I hope this makes sense

Comment: Can you enable more verbose logging and post the relevant output?

Answer (score 0):

I would say there is no active transaction and without a transaction JPA will not delete anything.

Try adding @Transactional to deletePost in the controller.

Comment: Hi, I tried putting that annotation to the deletePost method in the controller and it didn't have any effect

Comment: Can you provide the Spring Boot Application class. And what kind of additional configuration do you have?

Comment: Very little, The Spring boot application class is bare bones. No configuration.

Comment: I made a demo project where delete works fine: https://github.com/simasch/46360538 You can compare this with your solution.